# HTML Note Textbox

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm brand new to HTML and am having difficulties.

I have implemented a note page.

Where the user can type in a note and press submit.

When they press submit, I want the note that they typed in to display in a text box below, however Im struggling to implement that.

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>Form Name</legend>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Type Note">Note:</label>  
  <div class="col-md-5">
  <input id="Type Note" name="Type Note" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for=""></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button id="" name="" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

The output looks like...

```
Note:[==insertnotehere==]

Submit[button]

[Want my notes to display below in a text box]
```

If anyone has insight that would be awesome! Thank you!

Comment: Have you written any javascript? If so, please include it in the question.

Comment: I have not written any javascript. I guess ill have to look into utilizing JS for the textbox? @Soviut could reference any links that I can look at for completing this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function () {
  $(".form-horizontal").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($("#Type Note").val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
      <form class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>

          <!-- Form Name -->
          <legend>Form Name</legend>

          <!-- Text input-->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Type Note">Note:</label>
            <div class="col-md-5">
              <input id="Type Note" name="Type Note" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Button -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for=""></label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML is a declarative markup language so it can't do that level of interactivity on its own. Instead, you will need to write some javascript to make this work.

You'll need to write some javascript that does the following:

- Find the form element
- Listen for the `submit` event on said element
- Inside the event handler:

  - Cancel the default form submit, otherwise it will refresh the page
  - Create the HTML elements necessary to display the note
  - Populate the HTML with the value of the textbox
  - Add the elements into the DOM
  - Clear the value of the textbox